# Python xlwt how auto ajust text?

Tags: python, xlwt

I'm trying to auto-adjust text in a cell width-height, in Microsoft excel exists a command that can do this called "adjust text", My question is: can XLWT do this with any property or something?
This ask is not duplicated...

My problem:

Cell:
***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**
|........................................................|
|........................................................|
|........................................................|
|his is a example, is not duplicated ..as|
|**__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**|

Comment: I think the folks who have voted to close as duplicate have probably voted too soon, as this question is likely not about automatically adjusting the column width to fit the text.  However, this question is extremely difficult to understand.  As far as I know, there is no function in Excel called "adjust text".  There is "wrap text" and "shrink to fit", either of which *might* be the gist of this question, but it's too hard to tell.  Please edit the question to clarify!

Comment: You can't just say "this isn't a duplicate". What is different about yours? Why doesn't the solution there work for you? Explain, don't just announce and expect thousands of others to think "oh ok then"